# How to get crash logs of Testflight external testers on Xcode or iTunes connect?

Tags: ios, testflight, crash-log

Is there any ways to know what's wrong with someone's app. It is working on everyone else's device but this person.

The person tried removing the previous version and installing the new one, but it still does not work. I suspect that one of the files that I place in the documents folder might still be there... but the format of this file has changed since...

Answer (score 4):

Apple has a technote about this named [Debugging Deployed iOS Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1747/_index.html).

Also, if your tester syncs up their iPhone with a Macintosh or PC, iTunes also helpfully moves logs into predictable places [where they can be retrieved from](http://osxdaily.com/2012/08/07/get-crash-reports-logs-from-iphone-ipad/).

Comment: Thanks, the second part of your answer might be what I am looking for. I will wait for my tester to do it to see if that's the information I am looking for. And I'll wait to have more points to +1 your answer ;)

Comment: Ok, so I have managed to reproduce the bug on my tablet, so I can even check your link and try to find my own reports. However, there is nothing related to my app in the folder mentioned in the second link. Could it be because I archived it in release mode rather than debug?

Answer (score 0):

I am attempting to solve this logging of execution in TestFlight with the following simple approach...
In in-App Billing you really have to use TestFlight, so the problem is serious.

The "print("text") statements can be replaced in the code to calls to a func  printTestFlight(text:  String) which writes the strings to a database along with some identifier so you know the user.

This is quite simple and obvious, and to an extent it works.

If there are events which are logged by the os rather than teh user, then this approach misses those, notably the interesting ones around a crash. I'd be happy to hear from anyone who knows how to do thiso