# where can I find testflight internal testing and external testing crash logs in ios platform?

Tags: ios, testflight

Where can I find testflight internal testing and external testing  crash logs in ios platform? This is the description of ituns connect.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29515894/how-to-retrieve-crash-logs-from-testflight-app-in-pre-release-testing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29652638/how-to-get-crash-logs-of-testflight-external-testers-on-xcode-or-itunes-connect/29652941 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728516/how-do-you-view-testflight-crash-logs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522808/how-to-obtain-crash-logs-from-users-running-ios-9 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26131105/find-crash-logs-on-ios-8-device

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833428/way-to-see-crash-logs-for-an-ios-app-outside-of-an-xcode-debugging-session

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please make sure to **search for the question** before posting a new one . There is already countless numbers of this question posted.